# ffmpeg "enable" option with milliseconds

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have 20 minutes long video. Using -ss and -t i extracted some parts of this video and edited them in some sort of video editing tools (e.g. after effects). Now i want to place these parts to its original location. These parts are not required to start or end in the "0-millisecond location", means filter "overlay" with option enable=between(t,start_sec,end_sec) is not an option for me. How i can do that? It would be great if i could overlay multiple segments in one ffmpeg pass

Comment: enables times can have milliseconds. e.g. `enable=between(t,45,545,76.123) `

Answer (score 0):

Rejoin the parts with the concat filter. Let's say you have the parts from 2-3 min | 5-6 min | 12-13 min and want to rejoin them to the original video:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -i Edited_Part_1.mp4 -i Edited_Part_2.mp4 -i Edited_Part_3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]select='between(t,0,60)'[Orig_Part_1]; ^
[0]select='between(t,180,300)'[Orig_Part_2]; ^
[0]select='between(t,360,720)'[Orig_Part_3]; ^
[0]select='between(t,780,1200)'[Orig_Part_4]; ^
[Orig_Part_1][1][Orig_Part_2][2][Orig_Part_3][3][Orig_Part_4]concat=n=7:v=1:a=1[video];[video]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[video]" -c:v libx264 Output.mp4
```